# Improve SQL Query perofrmance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, query-performance

I have a complex query which takes 700ms to run on my machine. I found that the bottleneck is the **ORDER BY  at_firstname.value** clause, but how can I use indexes to improve this?

```
SELECT 
    `e`.*
    , `at_default_billing`.`value` AS `default_billing`
    , `at_billing_postcode`.`value` AS `billing_postcode`
    , `at_billing_city`.`value` AS `billing_city`
    , `at_billing_region`.`value` AS `billing_region`
    , `at_billing_country_id`.`value` AS `billing_country_id`
    , `at_company`.`value` AS `company`
    , `at_firstname`.`value` AS `firstname`
    , `at_lastname`.`value` AS `lastname`
    , CONCAT(at_firstname.value
    , " "
    , at_lastname.value) AS `full_name`
    , `at_phone`.`value` AS `phone`
    , IFNULL(at_phone.value,"N/A") AS `telephone`
    , `e`.`entity_id` AS `id` 
FROM 
    `customer_entity` AS `e`  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_entity_int` AS `at_default_billing` 
    ON (`at_default_billing`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) 
    AND (`at_default_billing`.`attribute_id` = '13')  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_postcode` 
    ON (`at_billing_postcode`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`)        
    AND (`at_billing_postcode`.`attribute_id` = '30')  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_city` 
    ON (`at_billing_city`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) 
    AND (`at_billing_city`.`attribute_id` = '26')  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_region` 
    ON (`at_billing_region`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) 
    AND (`at_billing_region`.`attribute_id` = '28')  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_country_id` 
    ON (`at_billing_country_id`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) 
    AND (`at_billing_country_id`.`attribute_id` = '27')  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_company` 
    ON (`at_company`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) 
    AND (`at_company`.`attribute_id` = '24')  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_firstname` 
    ON (`at_firstname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) 
    AND (`at_firstname`.`attribute_id` = '5')  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_lastname` 
    ON (`at_lastname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) 
    AND (`at_lastname`.`attribute_id` = '7')  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_phone` 
    ON (`at_phone`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) 
    AND (`at_phone`.`attribute_id` = '136')  
ORDER BY 
    `at_firstname`.`value` ASC LIMIT 20
```

This is execution plan :
[image]

EXPLAIN of Query :

```
'1','SIMPLE','e',NULL,'ALL',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'19951','100.00','Using temporary; Using filesort'
'1','SIMPLE','at_default_billing',NULL,'eq_ref','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID','6','lazurd.e.entity_id,const','1','100.00',NULL
'1','SIMPLE','at_billing_postcode',NULL,'eq_ref','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID','6','lazurd.at_default_billing.value,const','1','100.00','Using where'
'1','SIMPLE','at_billing_city',NULL,'eq_ref','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID','6','lazurd.at_default_billing.value,const','1','100.00','Using where'
'1','SIMPLE','at_billing_region',NULL,'eq_ref','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID','6','lazurd.at_default_billing.value,const','1','100.00','Using where'
'1','SIMPLE','at_billing_country_id',NULL,'eq_ref','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID','6','lazurd.at_default_billing.value,const','1','100.00','Using where'
'1','SIMPLE','at_company',NULL,'eq_ref','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID','6','lazurd.at_default_billing.value,const','1','100.00','Using where'
'1','SIMPLE','at_firstname',NULL,'eq_ref','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID','6','lazurd.e.entity_id,const','1','100.00',NULL
'1','SIMPLE','at_lastname',NULL,'eq_ref','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID','6','lazurd.e.entity_id,const','1','100.00',NULL
'1','SIMPLE','at_phone',NULL,'eq_ref','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE','UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID','6','lazurd.e.entity_id,const','1','100.00',NULL
```

---

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_entity_varchar` (
  `value_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value Id',
  `entity_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity Type Id',
  `attribute_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute Id',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity Id',
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Value',
  PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` (`entity_type_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID` (`attribute_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`value`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CSTR_ENTT_VCHR_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CSTR_ENTT_VCHR_ENTT_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTT_TYPE_ENTT_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=131094 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Customer Entity Varchar';
```

Comment: Optimizing a query with JOIN's with `ORDER BY` can be tricky..  If the MySQL optimizer access the the tables in the "wrong" order a sort algoritme is always required.. Ideally the Optimizer should access customer_entity_varchar first.. Can you provide table structures and a EXPLAIN output?

Comment: Please post the execution plan.

Comment: There's no filtering in this query: that means, it's essentially processing **all rows** from `customer_entity`. How many rows does it have?

Comment: You haven't given us enough info to help you. Please read this, especially the section on query performance, then [edit] your question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: @impaler it's list of users, maybe thousands

Comment: Can you post a native MySQL `EXPLAIN <query>` output? Besides we are still missing table structures.

Comment: @RaymondNijland EXPLAIN added to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now your query is:

1. Performing ALL left outer joins first.
2. Then `ORDER`ing the rows.
3. Then `LIMIT`ing the rows.

I would perform the strictly needed outer joins first, then ordering and limiting (to reduce to 20 rows), and finally I would do all the rest of the outer joins. In short I would do:

1. Performing minimal left outer join first. That is, two tables only.
2. Then `ORDER`ing the rows.
3. Then `LIMIT`ing the rows. This produce a max of 20 rows.
4. Perform all the rest of outer joins. At this point this is not thousands of rows anymore, but only 20.

This change should massively reduce the "Unique Key Lookup" executions. The modified query will look like:

```
select
  e.*
  , `at_default_billing`.`value` AS `default_billing`
  , `at_billing_postcode`.`value` AS `billing_postcode`
  , `at_billing_city`.`value` AS `billing_city`
  , `at_billing_region`.`value` AS `billing_region`
  , `at_billing_country_id`.`value` AS `billing_country_id`
  , `at_company`.`value` AS `company`
  , `at_lastname`.`value` AS `lastname`
  , CONCAT(firstname
  , " "
  , at_lastname.value) AS `full_name`
  , `at_phone`.`value` AS `phone`
  , IFNULL(at_phone.value,"N/A") AS `telephone`
from ( -- Step #1: joining customer_entity with customer_entity_varchar
SELECT 
    `e`.*
    , `at_firstname`.`value` AS `firstname`
    , `e`.`entity_id` AS `id` 
FROM 
    `customer_entity` AS `e`  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_firstname` 
    ON (`at_firstname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) 
    AND (`at_firstname`.`attribute_id` = '5')  
ORDER BY -- Step #2: Sorting (the bare minimum)
    `at_firstname`.`value` ASC 
LIMIT 20 -- Step #3: Limiting (to 20 rows)
) e
LEFT JOIN -- Step #4: Performing all the rest of outer joins (only few rows now)
    `customer_entity_int` AS `at_default_billing` 
    ON (`at_default_billing`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) 
    AND (`at_default_billing`.`attribute_id` = '13')  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_postcode` 
    ON (`at_billing_postcode`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`)        
    AND (`at_billing_postcode`.`attribute_id` = '30')  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_city` 
    ON (`at_billing_city`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) 
    AND (`at_billing_city`.`attribute_id` = '26')  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_region` 
    ON (`at_billing_region`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) 
    AND (`at_billing_region`.`attribute_id` = '28')  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_country_id` 
    ON (`at_billing_country_id`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) 
    AND (`at_billing_country_id`.`attribute_id` = '27')  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_company` 
    ON (`at_company`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) 
    AND (`at_company`.`attribute_id` = '24')  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_lastname` 
    ON (`at_lastname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) 
    AND (`at_lastname`.`attribute_id` = '7')  
LEFT JOIN 
    `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_phone` 
    ON (`at_phone`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) 
    AND (`at_phone`.`attribute_id` = '136')
```

Comment: Because SQL results are orderless by definition the outer SQL also requires a `ORDER BY e.firstname` to guarantee consistent results right?

Comment: If the ordering is really required, yes. At this point it's already filtered to 20 rows, so it may be unnecessary.

Comment: minor typo, on line 10 replace **   , CONCAT(at_firstname.value ** with **   , CONCAT(firstname **

Comment: @AVEbrahimi Typo fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `SELECT whole_mess_of_rows FROM many_tables ORDER BY one_col LIMIT small_number` is a notorious performance antipattern.  Why? Because it sorts a big result set, just to discard most of it.

The trick is to cheaply find out which rows are within that `LIMIT small_number`, then retrieve only those rows from the larger query.

Which rows do you want? It looks to me like this query will retrieve their `customer_entity.id` values.  But it's hard to be sure, so you should test this subquery.

```
           SELECT customer_entity.entity_id
             FROM customer_entity
             LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS at_firstname 
                       ON (at_firstname.entity_id = e.entity_id) 
                      AND (at_firstname.attribute_id = '5') 
            ORDER BY at_firstname.value ASC
            LIMIT 20
```

This should give the twenty relevant entity_id values. Test it. Look at its execution plan. Add an appropriate index to `customer_entity` if need be. That index might be `(firstname_attribute_id, firstname_entity_id, firstname_value)` But I am guessing.

Then you can put this at the end of your main query, right before ORDER BY.

```
 WHERE e.entity_id IN (
           SELECT customer_entity.entity_id
             FROM customer_entity
             LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS at_firstname 
                       ON (at_firstname.entity_id = e.entity_id) 
                      AND (at_firstname.attribute_id = '5') 
            ORDER BY at_firstname.value ASC
            LIMIT 20
      )
```

and things should be a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous Answers, but want to emphasize on more antipattern:  Over-noramlization.

Your schema is a curious (and inefficient) variant on the already-bad EAV schema pattern.

There is little advantage, and some disadvantage in splitting `customer_address_entity_varchar` across 5 tables.  Similarly for `customer_entity_varchar`.

An address should (usually) be stored as a few columns in a single table; no `JOINs` to other tables.

Likewise for firstname+lastname.

`Phone` could be another issue, since a person/company/entity could have multiple phone numbers (cell, home, work, fax, etc).  But that is a different story.